# Как сделать стабильный доступ к сайту из разных стран?

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, администрирование

Ввиду всё большего разграничения интернета, сейчас всё чаще наблюдаются проблемы с доступом к веб ресурсам из разны стран.
Мне важно, чтобы пользователи со всех стран имели беспрепятственный доступ к моему сайту.
В данный момент у меня есть VDS в Германии и РФ. И наблюдаю, периодические проблемы с доступами от некоторых операторов Украины в Германию (при этом в направлении рф работает), с других укр операторов обратная ситуация. Тоже самое и с рф.
Есть ли какие-то сервисы (cdn и балансеры это не то), или инструменты (чтобы найти подходящего разработчика) решающие такие проблемы?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если ограничения на уровне провайдера то бесполезно что-то делать со своим сайтом (насколько мне известно... в сетях не спец., если что...). Разве зеркала создавать для разных регионов

Comment: `Cloudflare` работает пока что везде.

Comment: @InDevX ограничения на IP у провайдеров нету. Т.е. проблема не в частных блокировках аля РКН.

Comment: @donRumata так это ж вроде как раз CDN, фаервол и т.п. И как я понимаю, он ничем не поможет, если у пользователя не будет доступа к IP моего хостинга

Comment: Ну тебе надо перенести сайт туда, где есть доступ у всех. Либо ты арендуешь 3-й сервер, вешаешь на него какой-нить лоад балансер, в ДНС прописываешь этот Ip и дальше кидаешь народ на тот или иной сервак.

Comment: @donRumata это конечно логично, перенести сайт где есть доступ отовсюду. Но сегодня укр провайдеры закроют трафик в рф, а завтра рф закроет трафик в мир (утрирую). 
А лоадбалансер как поможет решить проблему?

Comment: Перечитал ещё раз внимательнее вопрос, понял, что тупанул. Да, лоадбалансер немного про другое.